# C++ Overloading '--' postfix operator

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, postfix-operator

I'm trying to overload the '--' postfix operator. I have this code:

```
class Counter
{
 private:
    int count;
 public:
    Counter()
    { count = 0; }
    Counter(int c)
    { count = c; }

    void setCount(int c)
    { count = c; }
    int getCount()
    { return count; }

    int operator--()
    {
       int temp = count;
       count = count - 1;
       return temp;
    }
};
```

Then in `main` I have this function call:

```
 Counter a; 
 a.setCount(5); 
 cout << a-- << endl;
```

This gives me this error: 
`error: no ‘operator--(int)’ declared for postfix ‘--’, trying prefix operator instead`

But when I call the `operator--` function like this, it works just fine:

```
 cout << a.operator--() << endl;
```

What gives? It should be working fine.

Comment: That's because `a.operator--()` is equivalent to `--a`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For overloading postfix operator you need to specify a dummy `int` argument in the function signature i.e. there should also be a `operator--(int)`. What you have defined is a prefix decrement operator. See this [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.14) for more details.

Comment: And in case you(the OP) are wondering why, it's because they just needed some way to differentiate postfix from prefix. (maybe that was obvious)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that, thanks for your answer.
@BenjaminLindley Gotcha, so it's just a rule that one follows, makes sense thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Is it a standard for defining postfix and prefix versions? I mean why can't I define the operator++ with int parameter with prefix version?

Answer (score 8):

The postfix operator takes a `int` as an argument to distinguish it from the prefix operator.

Postfix:

```
int operator--(int)
{
}
```

Prefix:

```
int operator--()
{
}
```